# Does DFP serve in an iFrame (which hosts my site) on another Site?

Tags: google-dfp

Let's say I host a website: http://www.example.com

And I load ads on my website using DFP. And everything works out perfectly.

Now lets assume another site: http://www.anothersite.com is loading our site in an iframe.

My question is, does DFP load in that iframe ?  Does it depend on DFP settings such as 'Serve in Safeframe' option?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will, DFP doesn't know anything about the outer iframe.

Safeframe controls how the inner frame in which your ads are shown is [rendered](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/183282?hl=en) and it has nothing to do with any outer frames.

> SafeFrame is a cross-domain iframe that enables transparent and rich
>   interactions between page content and ads, while preventing ads from
>   accessing publisher data